# Служба запускающая службы

Tags: c#, service

У меня есть несколько собственных служб: *ServiceOne, ServiceTwo, ServiceDontService*. Эти службы я зарегистрировал в Windows и они отображаются в окне "Службы".

Теперь я хочу написать службу которая будет запускать все эти службы по порядку. Вопрос таков, как из кода запустить конкретную службу? Я не смог найти данной информации, подскажите пожалуйста как такое делается?

Это нужно мне что бы после включения компьютера автоматом запускалась данная служба, потом, к примеру, через 3 минуты запускалась служба ServiceOne, потом через 5 минут ServiceTwo, потом через 5 минут ServiceDontService и т.д.

Comment: Запустить процесс с параметрами: `net start ServiceOne`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11677680/5752652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, спасибо за ссылку @AK

Вот как по порядку можно запускать службы:

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var services = new string[] {"Телефонная связь", "Центр обновления Windows"};

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

            foreach (var service in services)
            {
                StartService(service);
            }
        }

        // Запуск службы
        public static void StartService(string serviceName)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            // Проверяем не запущена ли служба
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                // Запускаем службу
                service.Start();
                // В течении минуты ждём статус от службы
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                Console.WriteLine("Служба была успешно запущена!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Служба уже запущена!");
            }
        }
    }
```