# Перезапуск службы

Tags: c#, service, reload

В общем [у меня есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/916805/213987) свои собственные службы, например: **Service1**, **Service2**, **Service3** ... **ServiceN**.
Данные службы связаны друг с другом и не могут быть запущены пока предыдущая служба не будет запущена, то есть если не запущена служба **Service1**, то служба **Service2** не сможет запустится и т.д.

Мне нужно написать службу, которая по порядку запускала бы эти службы.
Я создал службу **StartService** и для примера через нее запустил службы по порядку, но столкнулся с проблемой: службы запускаются только тогда, когда будет остановлена текущая служба (**StartService**).

То есть получается мне нужно запускать службу **Service1**, после чего остановить свою службу **StartService** что бы запустилась служба **Service1**, после чего опять необходимо запустить свою службу **StartService**. Также нужно перед запуском каждой службы делать остановку выполнения кода на 5-10 секунд (что-то типо sleep), что бы предыдущая запущенная служба завершила свои манипуляции.

Вопрос как это сделать? Как заставить службу перезапускать саму себя?

Пример кода:

```
namespace WindowsService
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Для запуска служб
            ServiceController service;
            // Текущая служба
            ServiceController currentService = new ServiceController("StartService");

            var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

            service = new ServiceController("Service1");
            // Если служба не запущена
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                // Запускаем службу
                service.Start();

                // Перезапускаем текущую службу (Это не правильно)
                currentService.Stop();
                currentService.Start();
            }

            service = new ServiceController("Service2");

            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                // Запускаем службу
                service.Start();

                // Останавливаем текущую службу
                currentService.Stop();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А ты уверен, что дело в службе, которая запускает другие службы? МОжет быть остановка текущей службы приостанавливает работу текущего потока на несколько секу и за это время запускается запускаемая служба и создает иллюзия того, что служба тебе мешает.

Comment: Проверьте зависимости служб друг от друга (корневая не должна ни от кого зависеть, остальные запускайте по порядку зависимости) + используйте [Task.ContinueWith](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) в сочетании с Thread.Sleep Перезапуск службы самой себя делается через Environment.Exit в сочетании с простановкой автостарта, но вам это не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На другом форуме подсказали что можно запускать службы с помощью батника и не нужна создавать службу для запуска служб. Я об этом изначально не подумал. Сделал батник:

```
@echo on

net start Service1
SLEEP 10

net start Service2
SLEEP 10

net start Service3
SLEEP 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    service.Refresh();
}
```